# How to merge pandas dataframe rows if a specific index is same but data are mutually exclusive?

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I'm new-comer for pandas dataframe.
I'd like to merge rows which may be not standard merge/join case.
Problem statement is to merge following row data if index (A and B) are common but data (D E F) are mutually exclusive. index C is don't care

```
A B C D E F  
g h i - 1 -  
g h q 2 - -  
g i i - - 3  
h q i 4 - -  
g h q - - 5  
g h t - - 6
```

The expected results are ,

```
A B C D E F  
g h * 2 1 5  
g i i - - 3  
h q i 4 - -  
g h t - - 6
```

In this example, a row 'g h q - - 5' not 'g h t - - 6' was chosen for the first line. But it's okay if either one of those two lines is merged and the other remains

Here, 3 lines are merged. Merging first coming two lines and treating it as 'new reference' for ' g h q - -5' or 'g h t - - 6' is prefered, however, if possible, finding all mutually exclusive rows and merging at once is also okay. In real data, existance of 'g h q - - 5' and 'g h t - - 6' at the same time is really rare or none.

For the merged line, I expressed don't care C as * but I hope one of index C data, i.e. (g or h), is  chosen. Data coming first can be okay for index C of merged line.

Sorry for tricky operation but your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why `g h t - - 6` this row is present in your final output?

Comment: I don't want to drop any of data. What i'd like to do is a kind of outer join with don't care column (C).  
If (g h q  - - 5) is merged first and (g h * 2 1 5 ) is made, then (g h t - - 6) is no longer mutual exclusive for (g h * somehting) , in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Self-answer. Actual dataframe is little different but let me follow the dataframe of the example. For simplicity, coding for 'g h t - - 6' is omitted.

1. Split the dataframe using on NaN (this guarantees mutual exclusion)

```
df_D = df[~df['D'].isnull()]  
df_E = df[~df['E'].isnull()]
df_F = df[~df['F'].isnull()]
```

2. Keep the latest data in case of the same indices

```
df_D = df_D.sort_values(['A']).drop_duplicates(['A','B'],keep='last')  
...
```

3. merge data by update()

```
df_D.set_index(['A','B'], inplace=True)  
df_D.update(df_E.set_index(['A','B']), overwrite=False)  
df_D.update(df_F.set_index(['A','B']), overwrite=False)
```

4. reset index

```
df_D.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Finding the one row has data and fill its near empty cell.

```
Data_Frame = pd.DataFrame({'A':['g','g','g','h','g','g'],
                          'B':['h','h','i','q','h','h'],
                          'C':['i','q','i','i','q','t'],
                          'D':['-','2','-','4','-','-'],
                          'E':['1','-','-','-','-','-'],
                          'F':['-','-','3','-','5','6']})

Column_len=len(Data_Frame['A'])
exclusive_Data_Column =['D','E','F']
Duplicate_Value_Location=[]
Empty_location = []
Target_location = []
Elements = [(Data_Frame['A'][i], Data_Frame['B'][i]) for i in range(Column_len)]

for i, v in enumerate(Elements): ## Finding location of duplicated value.
    if ('g','h') == v:
        Duplicate_Value_Location.append(i)

for i in exclusive_Data_Column: ## Recording location of each data
    for x in Duplicate_Value_Location:
        if Data_Frame[i][x] == '-':
            Empty_location.append((i,x))
        elif Data_Frame[i][x] != '-':
            Target_location.append((i,x))

Target_row = [i[1] for i in Target_location]
Target_column = [i[0] for i in Target_location]
Empty_column = [i[0] for i in Empty_location]
Empty_row = [i[1] for i in Empty_location]
Unmovable_cell = []

Nearest_Target_row_index = [i for i, v in enumerate(Target_row) if v ==min(Target_row)][0]
Nearest_Target_row_value = Target_row[Nearest_Target_row_index]
Nearest_Target_column_value = Target_column[Nearest_Target_row_index]

Unmovable_cell.append((Nearest_Target_column_value,Nearest_Target_row_value))

Nearest_Empty_column_index = [i for i, v in enumerate(Empty_row) if v == Nearest_Target_row_value]

for column_index in Nearest_Empty_column_index:
    Empty_column_value = Empty_column[column_index]
    Empty_row_value = Empty_row[column_index]

    for Target_column_index, Target_column_value in enumerate(Target_column):
        Target_row_value = Target_row[Target_column_index]
        if Target_column_value == Empty_column_value and (Target_column_value, Target_row_value) not in Unmovable_cell:
            Merged_Target_column_value = Target_column[Target_column_index]
            Merged_Target_row_value = Target_row[Target_column_index]
            Unmovable_cell.append((Empty_column_value, Empty_row_value))

            Target_column = [v for i, v in enumerate(Target_column) if i != Target_column_index]
            Target_column.append(Empty_column_value)
            Target_row = [v for i, v in enumerate(Target_row) if i != Target_column_index]
            Target_row.append(Empty_row_value)
            Empty_column_2 = [v for i, v in enumerate(Empty_column) if i != column_index]
            Empty_column_2.append(Merged_Target_column_value)
            Empty_row_2 = [v for i, v in enumerate(Empty_row) if i != column_index]
            Empty_row_2.append(Merged_Target_row_value)
            Data_Frame[Empty_column_value][Empty_row_value] = Data_Frame[Empty_column_value][Target_row_value]
            Data_Frame = Data_Frame.drop(Target_row_value)

Data_Frame['C'][Nearest_Target_row_value] = '*'

print(Data_Frame)
```

Out come:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  g  h  *  2  1  5
2  g  i  i  -  -  3
3  h  q  i  4  -  -
5  g  h  t  -  -  6
```